# What are some of the best free resources for making profressional level iphone applications?

Tags: ios

I want to make an iphone app that has a fluid ui, great icons, fluid animations etc. and i have been trying to work on learning objective c all this past summer off of the web and I am nowhere close to being able to understand/build something like that. Sure, I understand all the programming concepts of objective c, I just dont know the how to put those in practice in a way that would produce the desired results that I described. What are some  free ways to learning how to do such things as that and how long would it take? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good old fashion practice. That's the best advice I can give you, and it's impossible for anyone to even gestimate how long it might take you. Only you can determine that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try TheNewBoston's tutorials. They cover not only learning the Objective C syntax, but get into OOP concepts, software design, and developing apps for iOS. Check him out at http://thenewboston.org/. If you would like to build apps visually, try http://www.appmakr.com/ for basic apps and http://www.appypie.com/iphone-apps-builder for more advanced ones.

Hope this helps!